# Storage setup for home servers

Tags: ssd, virtualization, zfs

I'm looking to set up my first home server, for multiple purposes, with Proxmox.

I already got the hint it's best to use 2 SSDs (of not too big size) for the actual Proxmox installation.

As far as I could understand it, ZFS (which Proxmox uses in those cases) is an "extension" to RAID. So is it permitted to use differently sized SSDs in one ZFS volume?

I already have an SSD which isn't sold anymore, so I'd either buy two identical ones (if required) or only one more which is roughly as big.

In short: What kind of problems can occur when using different disks in one ZFS volume, and how does it affect the performance of Proxmox? There's nothing on Google yet to this topic...

Comment: @davidpostill while the question makes incorrect assumptions (ehich can be corrected) I dont see how this is opinion based, and it should be reopened.

Comment: Asking, "What kind of problems can occur?" makes the question too broad. Instead, stick with asking if it's possible to use different size disks and whether doing so will incur a performance penalty.

Comment: I did ask exactly that, except I think other issues than just performance problems might occur.

Comment: I think it's a valid question, but @philhob is a bit misinformed about proxmox and zfs.